# Stuck figuring out the initialization sequence of ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, devops

This is a problem that has been hard for me to figure out.  I wanted to make a micro-service out of an ASP.NET Core Application.  I've been able to deploy .NET Core with Kestrel as an edge server and behind a proxy like Nginx. This seems semi-inconsequential, so haven't spent forever on it, but I can't figure out how to land on a different url other than root when my application starts up.  In other words, I've changed the default routing, this is an mvc application, and I added a prefix like this into `Startup.cs`:

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "SqlServer/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

In production, not a problem, doesn't matter what the default route is, but when I develop in VisualStudio and hit play, I get the blank browser because its pointing to "/" instead of "/SqlServer".  Any idea how to fix this?

Also relevant is `Program.cs`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 100;
                options.Limits.MaxConcurrentUpgradedConnections = 100;
                options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 10 * 1024;
                options.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate = new MinDataRate(bytesPerSecond: 100, gracePeriod: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                options.Limits.MinResponseDataRate = new MinDataRate(bytesPerSecond: 100, gracePeriod: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5001, listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.UseHttps("/Users/ryandines/DevelopmentCode/ExampleProject/testCert.pfx", "notMyPassword");
                });
            }).UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Comment: So you just want Visual Studio to launch the correct URL when you hit F5?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, also tried changing the url in launchSettings.json, and when I do dotnet run from cli it says: Overriding address(es) 'https://0.0.0.0:5001/SqlServer, http://0.0.0.0:5000/SqlServer'. Binding to endpoints defined in UseKestrel() instead,..... so maybe I just need to append something to IPAddress.Any, idk

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways of changing this setting.

#### Using Visual Studio

1. Right click on the project, select "Properties"
2. Select "Debug" tab
3. Next to the "Launch browser" checkbox, enter a URL that you want to start when the app runs.

#### Edit settings manually

Manually add a `launchUrl` property to the profile, for example:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:1234/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "<name of profile>": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:1234/cheese",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Local"
      }
    },
    //etc...
```